# Освещение по сеткам в c#

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. У меня две матрицы: для уровня и освещения. В качестве освещения рисуются поверх уровня черные блоки. Уровень из прозрачности работает как освещение. Я пробовал делать проверку на расстояние блока от источника света. Работает. Вот только я не могу понять как сделать проверку на наличия 'стен', которые не должны пропускать свет.

[image: Пример]

Comment: Объясняйтесь яснее. Какие матрицы? Какое освещение? Кто рисуется поверх какого уровня? Зачем делать какую-то проверку? Сформулируйте проблему так, чтобы всем стало понятно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Понятно, что если бы не было препятствий, то правильное значение `Illuminance` в каждой точке можно было бы рассчитать по формуле, указанной в правой части`:` `(1 - Round(...) / Radius),` положив `D = 1`.
- Для того, чтобы определить точки, в которых `D = 0,` авторы статьи, которой вы пользуетесь, предлагают делать `raycast` из точки источника света во все точки, аппроксимируя луч с помощью [алгоритма Брезенхэма.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm)

> После совершения `raycast'a` вы смотрите на результат растеризации луча, и если этот результат cодержит **хотя бы одну** точку, отмеченную на карте как препятствие, то `D = 0,` иначе `D = 1.`

- Вот примерный псевдокод алгоритма:

  ```
  ILLUMINANCE = { }

  foreach POINT in POINTS

      RAY = Bresenham(LIGHT_SOURCE, POINT)

      if (RAY.Contains(ANY OBSTACLE))
          ILLUMINANCE[POINT] = 0
      else
          ILLUMINANCE[POINT] = (1 - Round(...) / Radius)

  return ILLUMINANCE
  ```